# Associate a content type to a specific group in drupal commons

Tags: organic-groups, 7

How is possible to create a content type associated by default to a group in Drupal Commons?

I will try to explain. I have two groups: *literature* and *art*. Literature will have three content types i.e. *poetry*, *fiction* and *novels*. Art will have *painting*, *photography* and *drawings*.

I've created contents types and i've tried to associate them with the respective group by flagging the group and group content checkbox but nothing changed. I also followed the steps described here https://www.drupal.org/node/2014781 but when I try to add some content I still see the "*Post to specific groups*" radio option and select.

Help please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using one group content type, and "Literature" and "Art" are contents of that group type.

Tell me if I am wrong in my assumption.

You can use hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() to set a default field value for group field based current content type.

```
    function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
      $node = $form_state['node'];
      if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
       global $user;
       $groups = og_get_groups_by_user($user);
          if(is_array($groups)) {
          // This needs to be evaluated to check proper mapping of what field expect to set a default default field value
          if($node['#bundle'] == "poetry" || $node['#bundle'] == "fiction" ||$node['#bundle'] == "novels") {
          $form['group_field_name']['#default'] = $groups[0];  //Whatever index Literature has 
          }
          elseif($node['#bundle'] == "painting" || $node['#bundle'] == "photography" ||$node['#bundle'] == "drawings") {
          $form['group_field_name']['#default'] = $groups[1];  // Art's index
          }
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Chetna tks for your reply. I've two groups *literature* and *art* and i've tried to force the content types *poetry*, *fiction* and *novels* to write only in the Group *literature* and *painting*, *photography* and *drawings* to write only in the Group *Art*

Comment: I've created two new Content Types respectively *Literature* and *Art* and  in the `OG tab`  i've flagged  `Group` and  `Group content`. So in the Target bundles list now i've Group, *Literature* and *Art*. Then i've created other three content types *poetry*, *fiction* and *novels* flagged as a  `Group content`, selected the *Literature* Group form the Target bundles list and finally created the new Tabs for the `Commons browsing widget user interface` but this keep on write in all groups.

Comment: So, Literature and Art are two different content types and they are getting them listed in Target bundles list other group contents (painting, photography, drawings, poetry, fiction, novels).

So, now what you need to do is just to select "Literature" in Target bundle of poetry, fiction and novels content types, and save, and similarly select "Art" in Target bundle of painting, photography and drawings content types, and save.

This will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks it seem to works. Now the problem is: how to show the right  common browser widget tabs in the right group?

Comment: Hi Drupaler sorry... this will be my last question. I've create a module from your code: folder *my_module* and two files *my_module.info* and *my_module.module* that have your code with the right changes but commons doesn't want to install the module. where am I wrong? I'm missing some file?

Comment: No other file is required for this code, can you provide me the content of your info and module file so that I can detect the problem

Comment: Sure thanks! [module](http://pastie.org/pastes/10469783) and [info](http://pastie.org/10469784)

Comment: Hello @emanuele . Sorry for last response. I used you code and made custom module, and I was able to install it into my Drupal instance without any alterations. I hope you are using Drupal 7.

Comment: No probl. Thanks for your help! Sure i'm using drupal 7.x-3.9 with commons 7.x-3.30

Comment: I can install only with ssh command line so i put in sites/all/modules/ my zipped folder and than unzip with ssh. Finally i go to admin/modules and try to activate but it gives me a white screen and the module is not active. Maybe you've used the upload function inside drupal?

Comment: I use filezilla, I created a new folder in sites/all/modules and then created a .info and a . module file and put your code in them and saved. And then go to my website and enabled the module

Comment: sorry for my late reply. This is my apache error.log `[Wed Oct 21 04:27:44.943070 2015] [:error] [pid 24643] [client 151.28.222.205:54250] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/my_module/my_module.module on line 13, referer: http://52.18.244.208/?q=admin/modules`

Comment: Okay, got it, your line 13 is `if($node['#bundle'] == "contenuti_privati" {` you forgot to close condition bracket, so th line 13 should be `if($node['#bundle'] == "contenuti_privati") {`

Comment: I hope now it will work for you